# Value not updating in column in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have to perform below operations

1. Check for common data b/w two columns in table A; abc id = param ;
2. Query another table b and get some acc id based column abc_id from A
3. Update the table A column 'param' with this 'acc id'

The stored procedure is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_value 
AS
        v_account_id varchar2(20);
        v_abc_id A.abc_id%TYPE;
        v_cust_type A.cust_type%TYPE;
        v_param A.param%TYPE;
   
  cursor c1 is select abc_id , param, cust_type 
                   from A 
                   where abc_id=param;
  begin
  open c1;
 LOOP
             fetch c1 into v_abc_id,v_cust_type,v_param;
                     EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
             if (v_cust_type=1 or v_cust_type=2) then
            
             select account_id into v_account_id from B   where  B.abc_id=v_abc_id;
             update A  
             set A.param = acc_id 
             where A.abc_id = v_abc_id;
         end if;

        END LOOP;
        close c1;
END;
```

The column param in table is not getting updated

Comment: did you do a commit after calling the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Less likely,

- you created a procedure, but never executed it

If you did execute it, a few possible reasons:

- cursor didn't return any rows because no `abc_id` is equal to `param` which is *what*, exactly? It is not a parameter (procedure doesn't accept any parameters), so it must be a table column and there are no rows where `abc_id = param`
- if cursor returned some rows, `v_cust_type` isn't `1` and `v_cust_type` isn't `2` for any of these rows
- if they are, `acc_id` which - by the way, isn't declared so - if procedure compiles, then `acc_id` is actually a column in the `a` table for `abc_id = v_abc_id`

If procedure completed successfully and you're checking the outcome in another session, you can't see anything because you didn't `commit`.

Also, why do you `select account_id into v_account_id` and never use it (the `v_account_id`, I mean)?

---

Shortly, your code is full of logical errors, it would be a miracle if it actually did something.

Comment: update A  set A.param=v_account_id where A.abc_id=v_abc_id; this is where it is used 
missed during edit .